# How to automatically press buttons with java

Tags: java

I want the piece of code that simulates a button press. Basically telling the computer to press w. That's all I need

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.awt.Robot` with `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`

---

Below code simulates a key press of <kbd>W</kbd>

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
```

---

Read more:

- [Robot (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)
- [KeyEvent (Java Platform SE 7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)